# How to get APT to list all packages with files in a given path

Tags: apt, dpkg

I accidentally removed `/usr/sbin` from a few machines. I would like to find a way to query dpkg or apt to tell me all of the packages which have files in that path, so that I can re-install them.

The output should be a list of package names.

Does anyone have a handy `apt-***` or `dpkg` query that one could use?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do: `dpkg -S /usr/sbin`

This yields a list of packages that have files inside the directory given.

From `man dpkg-query`:

```
   -S, --search filename-search-pattern...
          Search for packages that own files corresponding to the
          given pattern.  Standard shell wildcard characters can be
          used in the pattern, where asterisk (*) and question mark
          (?) will match a slash, and blackslash (\) will be used as
          an escape character.

          If the first character in the filename-search-pattern is
          none of ‘*[?/’ then it will be considered a substring
          match and will be implicitly surrounded by ‘*’ (as in
          *filename-search-pattern*).  If the subsequent string
          contains any of ‘*[?\’, then it will handled like a glob
          pattern, otherwise any trailing ‘/’ or ‘/.’ will be
          removed and a literal path lookup will be performed.

          This command will not list extra files created by
          maintainer scripts, nor will it list alternatives.
```

Comment: can't believe it was sitting right in front of my face 